# CassandraIO : Inserting date field doesn't work

Tags: cassandra, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Following is the sample definition of the Cassandra table I have; `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (
   id int,
   data_date date,
   score double,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);`

I have created a TestTable Class which extends `Serializable` and the member `dataDate` data type has been defined as `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate`.

However when I try writing this data using CassandraIO.write I face the error
`Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate`

I Understand this error is because com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate doesn't implement `Serializable` interface

Hence I tried changing the data type of the member `dataDate` to `java.time.LocalDate` However this change results in the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [date <-> java.time.LocalDate]
```

So the question is; if I have a column of datatype date in Cassandra, how do I insert it using Apache Beam's CassandraIO

Answer (score 2):

Java driver can work with `LocalDate` from Java 8 only if you [add the jar with optional codecs, and register them](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/custom_codecs/extras/#jdk-8) - but it's not clear if you can intercept establishing of the connection to Cassandra in Beam job.

You need to add following dependency to pom.xml (adjust version to match version of driver in Beam):

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And register codec somewhere:

```java
import com.datastax.driver.extras.codecs.jdk8.LocalDateCodec;
import java.time.Instant;

cluster.getConfiguration().getCodecRegistry()
    .register(LocalDateCodec.instance);
```

Looking into Beam, it looks like that it uses Achiles that supports `@Codec` annotation, and already includes optional codecs, so you can annotate your field with `@Codec(com.datastax.driver.extras.codecs.jdk8.InstantCodec.class)`.

If it doesn't support Achiles, but instead uses Object Mapper from Java driver, then you can use [following annotation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/object_mapper/custom_codecs/#one-time-declaration): `@Column(codec = com.datastax.driver.extras.codecs.jdk8.InstantCodec.class)`

Comment: java.time.LocalDate worked using '@Column(codec = com.datastax.driver.extras.codecs.jdk8.LocalDateCodec.class)' annotation on field.